# Programming principles and practice using C++ - input validation

Tags: c++, validation

Here is some text from "Programming principles and practice" by Stroustrup:

> ```
> // somewhere: make ist throw an exception if it goes bad:
> ist.exceptions ( ist.exceptions() | ios_base::badbit );
> ```
>
> We could also decide to designate a character as a terminator:
>
> ```
> for (My_type var; ist>>var; ) {
> // read until end of file
> // maybe check that var is valid
> // do something with var
> }
> if (ist.fail()) {
> // use '|' as terminator and/or separator
>    ist.clear();
> char ch;
> if (!(ist>>ch && ch=='|')) error("bad termination of input");
> }
> // carry on: we found end of file or a terminator
> ```
>
> If we don’t want to accept a terminator — that is, to accept only end of file as the end — we simply delete the test before the call of `error()` . However, terminators are very useful when you read files with nested constructs, such as a file of monthly readings containing daily readings, containing hourly readings, etc., so we’ll keep considering the possibility of a terminating character.

- "If we don’t want to accept a terminator — that is, to accept only end of file as the end" but in the code test there is no check for an end of file?!

  ```
   if (!(ist>>ch && ch=='|')) 
       error ( "bad termination of input" );
  ```

So here it checks only for a terminator but not for an `EOF` because here an `EOF` puts  `std::cin` in fail state in which case the if statement throws. because here a bad input like an invalid character like '@' or EOF have the same effect which make the stream in a fail state. So normally to accept an end of file it should look like:

```
    if (!( (ist >> ch && ch=='|') || ist.eof() ) ) 
        error("bad termination of input");
```

So the code now doesn't throw in case of an end-of-file or a terminator but it does in case of a bad input (non-int).

Comment: That's a weird application of De Morgan's laws. More readable would be: `if (!(ist >> ch && ch=='|') && !ist.eof())`

Comment: @paddy: Am I right about my guesses and that is a mistake in the book?

Comment: No. You misunderstand the original text. It is providing an example where input is _required_ to be terminated by a specific character. It was _you_ who decided to make that optional, which I would say goes against the general thrust of what Stroustrup is trying to impart. The book is consistent with itself.

Comment: @paddy: In your example if the user enters an end-of-file (Ctrl+D on unix-like os) or (Ctrl+Z on windows) then this will make the condition false and thus it is negated to become true so EOF in your example makes the if-statement condition true which will throw an exception.

Comment: What are you talking about? You mean my rearrangement of your logic in the first comment? It's identical to yours.

Comment: @paddy: I am afraid not. In my case an EOF makes the condition false while yours makes it true.

Comment: In case of EOF: `!(ist >> ch && ch=='|')` is true and `!ist.eof()` is false. So the condition `!(ist >> ch && ch=='|') && !ist.eof()` is essentially `true && false` which is false. Feel free to take this issue up with the ghost of the Augustus De Morgan, but he will tell you that what I wrote is logically identical to what you wrote.

Comment: @paddy: You are right! Sorry I didn't notice the closing parenthesis of the first condition in your example. 
One thing: The end-of-file character in the book example causes throwing an exception but why he says then in the comment "`// carry on: we found end of file or a terminator`" as long as `EOF` makes the `if-statement` throw?!!!!

Comment: Examine the table of iostates (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate). The `if (ist.fail())` would have your desired behavior _IF_ the only error in the stream is EOF. That may or may not be true, depending on `My_type`. It is not a strict requirement for the fail-bit to be set when EOF is encountered, although it does say _"Note that in nearly all situations, if eofbit is set, the failbit is set as well"_. To shore that up a bit, you could replace `if (ist.fail())` with `if (!ist && !ist.eof())` instead of messing around with the other condition in the way you proposed.